# Django try upload file

Tags: python, django

When i try upload file got a problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...............

290, in pre_save if file and not file._committed:
AttributeError: 'MultiValueDict' object has no attribute '_committed'


class UserFiles(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
     file = models.FileField(blank=True,
                        upload_to='media/files/users_file/', null=True)
     def __unicode__(self):
         return u'%s' % self.user
```

How i  can fix that?

Comment: Add more details, you tried to upload the file through the admin interface or through a custom form ? If so is it a configuration problem or a code problem ? Show the specific files related to your problem.

Comment: Can you upload the related view as well?